# Running Tomcat from eclipse - error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I try to execute a tomcat 7 server. Eclipse version i 4.0.0 Juno
I have this error:

Failed to execute goal com.class.fc:maven-fc-plugin:3.2.0:component-stop (default-cli) on project fc-maven-core: Cannot proceed if Auth User not known. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

If I use the startup.bat everything is fine. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what is see, you are trying to stop `tomcat` using a `maven` plugin which fails because maven does not have any authentication infos (username/password) to present to tomcat.

To interact with tomcat you need to have a user setup in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and assign this user the appropriate roles for the action you want to request. After that you need to tell the maven plugin to use those authentication informations for sending commands to tomcat.

**EDIT**

Find [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) how you can configure the maven plugin